# How to access list of values from gradle.properties to build.gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have the following `gradle.properties`

```
version=2.1
paths=['/home/desk/hie', '/home/mydesk1/hai1', '/home/mydesk2/hai2']
sources=['/src/path/impl', '/src/path/src']
```

I need to access these paths and sources form `gradle.properties` to `build.gradle`

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir=${paths}
        }
    }
}
```

but `${paths}`  is not working.

Can you someone help to get out of this issue and how to use those list in `build.gradle` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following, which converts the paths `String` to an `Iterable` (that is, a `List`):

```
apply plugin: 'java'

def pathsList = Eval.me(project.ext.paths)

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = pathsList
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The above was working fine if I have only one list in **settings.gradle** file
If I have multiple lists how can I use it in **build.gradle**
//build.gradle
apply plugin: 'java'

def pathsList = Eval.me(project.ext.paths)

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = pathsList
        }
    }
}

restModel{

Comment: If I have multiple lists how can I use it in **build.gradle**
//build.gradle
apply plugin: 'java'

def pathsList = Eval.me(project.ext.paths)
def excludesList = Eval.me(project.ext.excludes)

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = pathsList
        }
    }
}

restModel {

        filter {
                excludes = excludesList
                }
}

**settings.gradle**
gradle.ext {
    paths = ['/home/desk/hie', '/home/mydesk1/hai1', '/home/mydesk2/hai2']
 excludes=['com.xxx.xxx.SiteAdmin','com.xxx.xxx.xxx.rest.LoginFacadeService']
}

Answer (score 0):

**You can share the value using `gradle` object**:

```
// settings.gradle
gradle.ext {
    paths = ['/home/desk/hie', '/home/mydesk1/hai1', '/home/mydesk2/hai2']
}

// build.gradle
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir = paths
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: getting the below issue when configure as suggested
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Personal'.
> Could not find property 'paths' on com.qmino.miredot.application.configuration.Filter_Decorated@517704.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.